# Programmatically calling toggle on a checkbox breaks gui in pyqt5

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt, pyqt5

I am creating a settings widget where a user clicks check boxes to select their preferred settings.  I want to have a 'Discard Changes' button that when pressed reverts the checkbox selections to the last save.

To do this i had saved the states of the check boxes from the last save in a dictionary, when discard changes is called, it will cycle through the dictionary, and if the checkbox's value is True, i will toggle, if False i will untoggle.  When doing this, the gui breaks and checkboxes disappear.

I've experimented and found out that if i call x.setChecked(True) once, it will work, but if toggle is called again on a different checkbox it will break. Any help will be appreciated!

```
class GlobalSettings(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.descList = [] #list that holds tire description elements in order
        self.metaHeader = []
        self.savedSettings = {}
        self.tempSettings = {}



    def __guiSetup__(self):
        self.metaCustomLine.setReadOnly(True)
        self.metaConstructionCode.toggle()

        self.tempSettings[self.metaCommandFileName] = False
        self.tempSettings[self.metaConstructionCode] = True
        self.tempSettings[self.metaDescription] = False
        self.tempSettings[self.metaDiameter] = False
        self.tempSettings[self.metaManufacturerDesc] = False
        self.tempSettings[self.metaRimDescription] = False
        self.tempSettings[self.metaRimMaterialDesc] = False
        self.tempSettings[self.metaSerialNumber] = False
        self.tempSettings[self.metaSize] = False
        self.tempSettings[self.metaTestTypeDesc] = False
        self.tempSettings[self.metaTestTypeID] = False
        self.tempSettings[self.metaTitle] = False
        self.tempSettings[self.metaWidth] = False

        for x in self.tempSettings:
            self.savedSettings[x] = self.tempSettings[x]


    def discardChanges(self):
        for x in self.savedSettings:
            if self.savedSettings[x]:
                x.setChecked(True)
            else:
                x.setChecked(False)


    def refresh(self):
        return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears calling QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents() is necessary when processing signals within a loop.

```
def discardChanges(self):
    for x in self.savedSettings:
        if self.savedSettings[x]:
            x.setChecked(True)
            QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        else:
            x.setChecked(False)
            QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
```